# Redirect domain to new domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've looked around and around and couldn't find anything that worked specific to my needs.

I need to figure out how to mass redirect all URLs with the old domain to the new domain. For example:

http://www.olddomain.com/blog-post-title
to
http://www.newdomain.com/blog-post-title

The URI is always the same I just need the htaccess to recognize when a URL has this and redirect it to the new domain.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to work on [accepting answers to your previous questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), or else contributors will be less likely to help you in the future.

Comment: Apologies. I thought I had done it in the past but apparently not. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect your old domain wholesale to the new one, you can just use the [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive

```
Redirect / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

Comment: I actually need for the htaccess to recognize when the URI uses the old domain. I've already setup a redirect on the domain but I need it to be more specific for all the interior links.

Comment: @Aikyrie You can do this with mod_rewrite, of course. But just recognizing it, doesn't buy you anything. What exactly do you want to do with this information?

Comment: I was hoping there's an easier way to redirect URLs using the old domain to be redirected using the same URI with the new domain. For example, olddomain.com/blog-post would redirect to newdomain.com/blog-post. There's over a thousand so I was hoping for an easier solution than doing 1 to 1 redirects by hand.

Comment: @Aikyrie You don't need to do it one by one. The `Redirect` above already does the redirect for the entire domain.

Comment: I tried it and it did work thank you! I'm sorry I misunderstood!

Comment: @Aikyrie No problem, everything is fine. I'm glad it works. :-)