# htaccess redirect if user attempts to go to old URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a very urgent issue. A site I manage is trying to change its branding, the site has been transferred but the only way to setup the site with my terrible host is to add the new url as an alias to the old one.

I need to add a rule to redirect the user somewhere else (google or something) if they attempt to go to any page on the old URL.

I've been looking for something like this for a few hours and can;t find any example that when adapted works and I really need to get it sorted before the weekend

Comment: If you want to redirect from old domain to new domain, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15236332/1741542.

Comment: Not all the time though, only when they tried to specifically access the old address as they're the same installation and ties to the same account.

Comment: You need a redirect, when a user requests `www.olddomain.com/abc/def` but not when requesting `www.olddomain.com/xyz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if request comes for the old URL then redirect it to your home page
RewriteRule ^old-url/?$ / [R=301,L,NC]
```